# Add contents to the end of a float array like this

Tags: java

Hey Guys, I've got the following float array...

```
         public static float camObjCoord[] = new float[] {



             -2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
              2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
             -2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
              2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,

             -2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
             -2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,
              2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
              2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,

             -2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
             -2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
             -2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
             -2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,

              2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
              2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,
              2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
              2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,

             -2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
              2.0f,  1.5f, -6.0f,
             -2.0f,  1.5f, -6.0f,
              2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,

             -2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
             -2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
              2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
              2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,



                 -2.0f,  2.5f,  -6.0f,
                  2.0f,  2.5f,  -6.0f,
                 -2.0f,  4.5f,  -6.0f,
                  2.0f,  4.5f,  -6.0f,

                 -2.0f,  2.5f, -10.0f,
                 -2.0f,  4.5f, -10.0f,
                  2.0f,  2.5f, -10.0f,
                  2.0f,  4.5f, -10.0f,

                 -2.0f,  2.5f,  -6.0f,
                 -2.0f,  4.5f,  -6.0f,
                 -2.0f,  2.5f, -10.0f,
                 -2.0f,  4.5f, -10.0f,
                                      2.0f,  2.5f, -10.0f,
                  2.0f,  4.5f, -10.0f,
                  2.0f,  2.5f,  -6.0f,
                  2.0f,  4.5f,  -6.0f,

                 -2.0f,  4.5f,  -6.0f,
                  2.0f,  4.5f, -6.0f,
                 -2.0f,  4.5f, -6.0f,
                  2.0f,  4.5f, -10.0f,

                 -2.0f,  2.5f,  -6.0f,
                 -2.0f,  2.5f, -10.0f,
                  2.0f,  2.5f,  -6.0f,
                  2.0f,  2.5f, -10.0f,
        };
```

I've got a method after it which I would like to add values to the end of the array but it's telling me it can't find camObjCoord, any idea why?

Comment: Someone tell this guy to use a `List<Point3D>` or something!

Comment: I havent written it, but it would be located below the above code I was just doing `camObjCoord[x] = y` but it claims it couldn't find camObjCoord

Comment: You're missing the most interesting part of the code, that is where you're trying to use the array. The initialization of the array is not that interesting, at least not all the values. Just add the method.

Comment: @polygenelubricants
He might need the array for a shader or something which might not be able to work with a list. But generally, I agree.

Comment: Mind showing us the error you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some important points:

- Arrays in Java are fixed-length objects. You can't modify the length of an array once it's created.

  - You can create *another* array of size `N+1`, copying all `N` elements, and then adding the extra element, but this is a costly highly-inefficient `O(N)` operation to add a single element
- Based on the name, formatting and the pattern in the numbers, it looks like every 3 `float` is a 3D point. You should seriously considering defining a `Point3D` custom type to hold your data.
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Prefer lists to arrays*; you should consider having a `List<Point3d>`
- Unless you have a good reason to use `float`, you should use `double` instead

Comment: None of this answers the original question, of course. Andreas has some ideas, but unless we get more info, we can't really help.

Comment: Java Puzzlers, Puzzle 34: Down for the Count: "When you use floating-point, use `double` rather than `float` unless you are certain that `float` provides enough precision and you have a compelling performance need to use `float`. The times when it's appropriate to use `float` rather than `double` are few and far between."

Answer (score 3):

Adding to an array is not possible because an array can't change in size. So you either use a Collection structure or you create a bigger array, copy the old values to the new one and fill the empty space at the end wih your new values.

But that was not the question - you'll be able access the array

- with `camObjCoord` from the same class
- with `MyClass.camObjCoord` from a class within the same package (assuming `MyClass` is the class that contains `camObjCoord` and
- with `MyClass.camObjCoord` from a class within of a different package if this class imports `MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not telling you it can't find the variable, but rather that you're not allowed to add items to an array.  Arrays are fixed-length; if you want an extensible array-like data structure, use ArrayList.  Alternatively, define your array initially with the size you need it to have.