# Make a List<Point3D> , add points and draw using glDrawArrays

Tags: java, opengl

This is a follow up question from [Add contents to the end of a float array like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204189/add-contents-to-the-end-of-a-float-array-like-this) . I'm looking to dynamically create 3D boxes. Here's my Questions

- I want to add a box to the list e.g add....

  ```
  // FRONT
           -2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
            2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
           -2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
            2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
           // BACK
           -2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
           -2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,
            2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
            2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,
           // LEFT
           -2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
           -2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
           -2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
           -2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,
           // RIGHT
            2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
            2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,
            2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
            2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
           // TOP
           -2.0f,  1.5f,  -6.0f,
            2.0f,  1.5f, -6.0f,
           -2.0f,  1.5f, -6.0f,
            2.0f,  1.5f, -10.0f,
           // BOTTOM
           -2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
           -2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
            2.0f, -1.5f,  -6.0f,
            2.0f, -1.5f, -10.0f,
  ```

The above values would make up 1 box, how would I do so?

- I'd like to use `glDrawArrays()` to then draw the entire list (all of the boxes) how would I make it do so?

  ```
          FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float[] arr) {
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length*4);
  bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
  fb.put(arr);
  fb.position(0);
  return fb;
  ```

  }

keep in mind, I'm sending everything through a floatbuffer. and then drawing like so..

```
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);          
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,12, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,16, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,20, 4);
```

I'm completely new to Point3D, OpenGL and graphics in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a basic example app up and running with OpenGL from Java? You may also want to add the JOGL tag to this.

Comment: Yes, I do. I can add boxes, rotate the world, do other stuff but now I need to use a data structure that will allow me to dynamically create and draw n cubes.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've added the opengl tag I understand why you need float[] structures (or at least floats instead of doubles).

Here is [demo application](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/vertex-arrays-in-jogl.html). To me it looks like a good piece of code for studying opengl basics, including the vertex arrays. From other question I see that you work on an android project. So I just hope that it's applicable to android too.

Comment: Problem with that is I have to send it through a `Floatbuffer` and then draw it.. I've edited my question to show more code

Comment: +1; I know nothing about OpenGL in Java, and I'm not sure how applicable my answer on the other question is for OP, but I hope others can guide him.